# Can I run 2 active polls on my site?

Tags: blocks, polls

We have a regular poll on our homepage, which I set up by selecting 'most recent poll'.

However, I want to add a different poll on a seperate page on my website. Can I do this? I can't find polls as a block or node function other than 'most recent poll'

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Define an auxiliary content type (say MyPoll).

I added a Node reference CCK field to standard Poll and a CCK Node Referrers (backreference) field to MyPoll. You can then easily create one (or even more!) polls as "children" of your MyPoll node, and attach their teaser content (the voting widget) to the MyPoll node.

As MyPoll is a "standard" content type, you can do whatever you want with it in views... including the display of the referred poll widgets. It's not straightforward...

I was inspired by http://www.lullabot.com/articles/photo-galleries-views-attach. Look at it this way: "galleries" are "mypolls", and "images" are "polls".

Answer (score 0):

You can also see and try this module [Pollfield](http://drupal.org/project/pollfield)